# convert characters in a string to a numerical value, find the sum, and then log the sum and the string

Tags: javascript, arrays

I want to take a string that contains a name and convert each character to a numerical value. Then find the sum of all the characters numerical value. Currently it is only summing the value of the first char in the string using .charAt()
I know I need to do the following.
1. create a function with for to go through each character in string
2. create if else statements to find the numerical value of each character in the string and send the sum to nameSum.
3.console.log the name and its numerical value. 
4. later i will deal with upper and lowercase.
5. ultimately i want to pull from an array that contains var that have strings for names.

```
   var name1 = 'bill';

const findNameVal = (name) => {
  let nameSum = 0;
  let cardCheck = name;
    for (let i=0; i < cardCheck.length; i++) {
        if (name1.charAt(i) === 'a') {
            return nameSum =+ 1; 
    } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'b') {
        return nameSum =+ 2;
    } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'i') {
        return nameSum =+ 9;
    } else if (name1.charAt(i)=== 'l') {
        return nameSum =+ 12;
    } 
}
}
console.log(`The name is: ${name1} and the numerical value is ${findNameVal(name1)}`);
```

Comment: `return nameSum =+`? You don’t want to return early, so return `nameSum` _after_ your `for` loop. Summing is done with `+=`, not `=+`.

Comment: working now with return outside for loop.  and changed =+ to +=

Comment: Why is my question downvoted?  I couldn't find anything similar for js.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the string into a lower-cased array of characters, then use `reduce` to iterate over the characters and find their character code. Eg `'a'.charCodeAt()` is `97`, and `'b'.charCodeAt()` is `98`, so you can just subtract 96 from each code found:

```js
var name1 = 'bill';

const findNameVal = (name) => {
  const lowercaseArr = [...name.toLowerCase()];
  return lowercaseArr.reduce((a, char) => a + char.charCodeAt() - 96, 0);
}
console.log(`The name is: ${name1} and the numerical value is ${findNameVal(name1)}`);
```

Comment: [It's not required.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charCodeAt#parameters). *If index is not a number, it defaults to 0.*